# Onclick function not working html

Tags: javascript, html, django, onclick

Below is the code that is used in my html.I have written a javascript which works on onclick.whenever i press it javascript is not working.I tried to print alert inside script but the reposnse is not going to the script.This was working earlier,but suddenly its stopprd working.Following is my code:

```
<a href="" onclick="add_cart({{product.id}})" title="Add To Cart" class="submit_btn   

add_btn" >+</a>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_cart()
    {
        alert('hi');
        //checking the attributes valid or not
        var attr_ids=[];
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
            attr_ids.push($(this).val());

        });
        var attr_length = attr_ids.length;
        var min_attr = $('#min_attribute').val();
        var max_attr = $('#max_attribute').val();
        if(parseInt(min_attr)<=parseInt(attr_length))
        {
            if(parseInt(attr_length)<=parseInt(max_attr))
            {
                $( "#add_cart_form" ).submit();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#attr_error').html("please select less than"+max_attr +"attributes")
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(attr_length<min_attr)
            {
                $('#attr_error').html("please select at least"+min_attr +"attributes")
            }
            if(attr_length>max_attr)
            {
                $('#attr_error').html("please select less than"+max_attr +"attributes")
            }
        }

        $( "#add_cart_form" ).submit();

    }

</script>
```

Please help me with this...

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: There's no error in console.

Comment: Are you using some other frame work because you are passing uncommon parameter into `add_cart onclick="add_cart({{product.id}})`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<a href="#" onclick="add_cart('{product.id}')" title="Add To Cart" class="submit_btn add_btn" >+</a>
```